# Meteor JS y Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

¿ Como puedo llamar metodos nativos de java a través de cordova con Meteor ?  He tratado con cordova.exec() declarando plugins, pero no se exactamente donde declarar estos plugins. he encontrado que deberia declararlos de la siguiente manera, en el archivo config.xml

```
 <feature name="namePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="name package" />        
</feature>
```

Además de eso, declaré dentro del proyecto android generado por cordova una clase que hereda de CordovaPlugin con sus respectivos métodos.

Todo eso sin éxito porque cada vez que intento correr el proyecto Meteor sobreescribe el archivo config.xml y elimina la declaración del plugin.

También he editado el archivo android.json para agregar el plugin desde ahí sin ningún resultado

Comment: ¿y la pregunta es si hemos trabajado con Meteor? ¿O que no encuentras el objeto `cordova`? ¿O quieres saber cómo crear funciones en `window`?

Comment: La pregunta puntual es ¿ como declarar plugins cordova para poder llamar metodos java a través de Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

No es posible.

O por lo menos no directamente. Cordova no puede conectarse a Java directamente.

La forma en la que lo puedes hacer es creando un **Webservice** con Java. Y desde al aplicacion consumes dicho servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la pregunta correcta que deberías hacer es "Como crear un plugin para cordova"

Si lo que quieres es sobreescribir el archivo config.xml tienes que crear una carpeta llamada "cordova-build-override" en el top (al mismo nivel de las carpetas server o client) dentro de esa carpeta tienes que generar el árbol de carpetas hasta llegar al config.xml de android, ese archivo reemplazará al generado.

En este enlace esta la documentacion oficial https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#advanced-build

Y otro sobre creacion de plugins https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html